# Different between array_replace and array_replace_recursive

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am having a difficult to understand the difference between these two function in php `array_replace` and  `array_replace_recursive`.

```
array array_replace_recursive ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

and

```
array array_replace ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

and thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what the word *recursive* means? Its basically that if you have multi-dimensional arrays, it the function will be performed on the sub-arrays too instead of just the parent array.

Comment: Look at *Example #1* at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php, as it shows the difference in results from the 2 functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference arises when you have arrays within arrays. Taking from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php), let's create two arrays:

```
$base = array('citrus' => array( "orange") , 
              'berries' => array("blackberry", "raspberry"), 
             );
$replacements = array('citrus' => array('pineapple'), 
                      'berries' => array('blueberry')
                );
```

If we do

```
$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements);
```

We will get

```
Array
(
[citrus] => Array
    (
        [0] => pineapple
    )

[berries] => Array
    (
        [0] => blueberry
    )

)
```

where the array "blueberry" has replaced the array "blackberry","raspberry". If instead we do

```
$basket = array_replace_recursive($base, $replacements);
```

we will get

```
Array
(
[citrus] => Array
    (
        [0] => pineapple
    )

[berries] => Array
    (
        [0] => blueberry
        [1] => raspberry
    )

)
```

Now the first element in the array "blueberry" has replaced the first element in the array "blackberry","raspberry". So it's an array replacement within an array replacement, or a recursive replacement.